# Get attachment if matches a variable

Tags: posts, images, media-library, variables

how do I match an image title from the media library to a variable then echo that image? this is my current code...

```
    <?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => null,
    ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );

if ($attachment->post_title == $programme) {

    echo the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$attachments` holds array of posts, you are missing something like:

```
$attachment = $attachments[0];
```

or

```
foreach( $attachments as $attachment )
```

**Update**

Nope, like this:

```
foreach( $attachments as $attachment )
    if ($attachment->post_title == $programme) {

        echo the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: hmmm, nearly now I get Missing Attachment?

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, still no joy, I get nothing:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => null,
    ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );

if ($attachment->post_title == $programme) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Please use comments or edit your original answer for updates (unless it's final working and so answer-worthy solution).

Answer (score -1):

Sorted for anyone else wanting to do this the code is:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => null,
    ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {

    if ($attachment->post_title == $programme) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail', false, false);
            break;
        }

}
?>
```